# Convert lists of list into List of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to convert this list of lists to list of dictionaries as the following format using python3.

```
[['a','b','c'],['d','e'],['f','g']]
```

The value to key need to be 1 for all list elements. Any guide please.

```
[{'a':1,'b':1,'c':1},{'d':1,'e':1},{'f':1,'g':1}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a single line using a combination of list and dictionary comprehension. Assume `a` is your original list:

```
a = [['a','b','c'],['d','e'],['f','g']]
```

The you would get your desired output with:

```
b = [{k: 1 for k in i} for i in a]
```